# Understanding computational & statistical tradeoffs

Tags: mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

Lots of people talk about computational vs statistical tradeoffs e.g. https://stat.mit.edu/research/statistical-and-computational-tradeoffs/. I have two questions.

1. Can someone please provide some simple examples?
2. Can someone please explain under what conditions these tradeoffs emerge and why?

Comment: Not sure if this is the kind of thing you are looking for, but [MCMC estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) is guaranteed to converge to the target distribution eventually (in terms of iterations) under widely achievable assumptions, but under many circumstances you do not necessarily know, in the immortal words of Morrissey and Johnny Marr, **how soon is now?** before you can rely on it having actually converged.